# OR operator not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

what is alternative of

```
if(s!=1||s!=2||s!=3)
 {

   alert("SUCCESS");
  }
```

It is not working. So Please suggest.

Comment: what did you want to happen?

Comment: It works perfectly  fine

Comment: works just fine. here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kukicvladimir/vbeLdtpg/1/)

Comment: Presumably it doesn't work because there is no value of s that will not alert ... if you want s to be anything but 1,2,3 use &&.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons - verify you convert types

Comment: If something isn't `1`, OR if it isn't `2` ... is never true, it can't be either not one thing, or not another, the logic seems flawed, you probably wanted `&&`

Comment: @adeneo I believe you meant *"is **always** true"*.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - yes of course, always true, not never true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very unlikely that you wanted:

```
 if(s!=1||s!=2||s!=3)
```

Since for all values of `s`, this is always true.

`||` means that the expression is true if either the left side or right side is true.

Maybe you wanted it to be true if s was not 1, 2, or 3.  Even though you use the word "or" in that sentence, in a logic expression, you say "s is not equal to 1 AND s is not equal to 2 AND s is not equal to 3"

If that's what you want, then the code is

```
if (s!=1 && s!=2 && s!=3)
```